Postfix Adding Extra 'Received' Header on Port 10025 Listener with Amavis - How to Suppress It?
I'm running a Postfix mail server configured with Amavis to scan emails for viruses. After Amavis processes the email, it sends it back to Postfix on a dedicated listener on port 10025 for final delivery. However, this setup is causing Postfix to add an extra Received header that I can't seem to suppress. This additional Received header looks like it's generated by the Postfix listener on 127.0.0.1:10025.
Here's my setup:
Postfix main.cf:
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
smtpd_proxy_options = speed_adjust

Postfix master.cf:
smtp-amavis   unix   -   -   n   -   2   smtp
  -o syslog_name=postfix/amavis
  -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
  -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
  -o max_use=20
  -o smtp_tls_security_level=none

127.0.0.1:10025   inet   n    -     n     -     -    smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/10025
  -o content_filter=
  -o mynetworks_style=host
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
  -o local_recipient_maps=
  -o relay_recipient_maps=
  -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
  -o smtp_tls_security_level=none
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none
  -o smtpd_received_header=no
  -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
  -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
  -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
  -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
  -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
  -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
  -o smtpd_milters=
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_address_mappings

Problem:
After email processing, Postfix adds this extra Received header:
Received: from localhost (mx.domain.com [127.0.0.1])
    by mx.domain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id R69B85E11;
    Fri,  8 Nov 2024 23:00:07 +0400 (+0400)

I've managed to remove the Amavis-generated Received header using this setting in /etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user:
$allowed_added_header_fields{lc('Received')} = 0;

However, the Postfix-generated header at the 10025 listener persists, and I haven't found a way to prevent it from being added.

I tried adding header_checks and smtpd_header_checks; they can remove the original Received header but not the last one added at port 10025.
I also tried adding a cleanup service directly linked to 10025 in master.cf, but with no success.

How can I configure Postfix to prevent this extra Received header from being added on the 127.0.0.1:10025 listener? Is there a specific setting I’ve missed, or is there another way to suppress this header from Postfix?

Why remove a generally harmless & occasionally useful header? What is the actual problem?

Basically, I don't want to reveal the specific applications or services running on my server. In this specific case, it's not leaking anything sensitive, but a localhost hop. What I'm really curious about here is why I'm unable to remove this information? Where does this get added? Why isn't the header_checks configuration being applied to it?

Tracing each hop in the delivery chain is needed for things like shutting down loops (see hopcount_limit). If you are worried about leaking internals, it may be entirely sufficient to redact sensitive trace headers on outgoing messages (e.g. when someone forwards the message as-is or attached in full) or on final message delivery (e.g. in a sieve script).

To solve the problem I had to remove no_header_body_checks from:
-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,...

It was the cause of header_checks not being applied.
